# What exactly did Dominique say to Karol at the end of "Three Colors White"?

Tags: dialogue, ending, three-colors-trilogy, three-colors-white

I watched "Three Colors White" yesterday. In that movie, when Dominique was in prison and Karol was standing near the prison and was looking at her window, she was saying something to him in sign language and that made him cry.

Can anyone tell what she was saying to him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in the film's [IMDb FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111507/faq):

> When Karol watches Dominique with the binoculars, she uses the sign language saying, ("quand je me libère de prison, toi et me, on part ensemble, oui? Ou on reste ici, ensemble, on se marie.") **"When I get out of prison, you and me, we'll leave together, OK? Or we'll stay here together and get married again,"** (as Domique shows the act of putting a ring on the left hand on the ring finger), explained by Julie Delpy in [the] bonus feature of the DVD.

Here's Delpy explaining exactly what she said in that scene and why:

Comment: Thanks for help, i agree with that..accept..but can you tell why dominique went to jail..was that becuase of Karol?

Comment: He framed her for his own murder or something? It's been years...

Comment: yeah karol planned his fake death,,but why she caught by cop ?

Comment: She just got caught? I don't remember that part, sorry. You can put it up as a question if you want, I'm sure someone remembers this better than me.

Comment: ok sure and can you suggest soundtrack of that movie??

Comment: Suggest what? I'm not sure what you mean. The film *has* a soundtrack, you can find it [here](http://www.amazon.com/dp/samples/B000000W6E).